# How to provide selection criteria to Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm currently working on a Crystal Report and my problem is this:

I want to show the Crystal Report on another page, I mean when admin select any `Employee` from `DropDownList` and click on 'view report' then the report can be shown on another page. How can i do this?

***EDIT:***

In my `AdminReport.aspx.cs` page I have loaded employee names and select one `Employee` from `DropDownList`, after clicking on the 'view' button which can redirect into new `Report.aspx` page. I have put my report binding source into this page[(`Report.aspx.cs`).

Here is my code:

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("CryRepTest.rpt"));
rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "password_1");
var empid = drpdwnEmployee.SelectedItem.Value;
rpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{AdminReportView.EmployeeID}=" + empid;
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

Can anyone knows??? plz help me...

Comment: tell how you bind your report source

Comment: Please provide more specific details of your current situation along with information regarding what you've tried and exactly what you're having trouble with, this will improve your question and enable people to help more easily and directly.

Comment: If it's related to Crystal Reports, tag it accordingly, not title it.

Answer (score 0):

In similar requirement before I did this

First created a class called ReportDto

```
public class ReportDto { public string EmployeeId {get;set;} //Other required properties  }
```

On AdminReport.aspx.cs

```
OnButtonClick () //Whatever event of ViewReport you may have
ReportDto dto = new ReportDto() { EmployeeId = drpEmployee.SelectedValue };


Session["CurrentReport"] = dto;
Response.Redirect(ViewReport.aspx)
```

On ViewReport.aspx on Page_Load

```
ReportDto dto = (ReportDto)Session["CurrentReport"]
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();      
rpt.ReportSelectionForumula = "{AdminReportView.EmployeeID}=" + dto.EmployeeId
```

and your other regular statements thereafter. This is just a sample to give you an idea. Beauty of this is that if your filters changed or increased, just add properties to your Dto class and you transport them together here. (Note you will have to do the due dilegence of checking for null, assigning null to session so that next time you get new values etc).